# kubernetes kubesrpay configuration - disabling insecure port AND setting kube_api_anonymous_auth as false

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

by default kubespray cluster configuration has.

```
kube_apiserver_insecure_port: 8080 # (http)
# Set to 0 to disable insecure port - Requires RBAC in authorization_modes and kube_api_anonymous_auth: true
#kube_apiserver_insecure_port: 0 # (disabled)
```

we are looking for disabling the insecure port (kube_apiserver_insecure_port) AND kube_api_anonymous_auth both.

Is this the limitation of kuberspray installation? 
Can it be done post installation?
How can we configure the same post installation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible by

```
kube-apiserver --insecure-port=0
```